# compiler's detail of this pointer and virtual functions

Tags: c++, pointers, virtual-functions, vtable, this-pointer

I'm reading Bjarne's paper: "[Multiple Inheritance for C++](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAAahUKEwiyyr2ZhoTGAhUCd60KHXGxAJI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.usenix.org%2Fpublications%2Fcompsystems%2F1989%2Ffall_stroustrup.pdf&ei=uZx3VfKJJoLutQXx4oKQCQ&usg=AFQjCNHPqDyiu0Gc700VQ-3h_98GX0A_Ig&sig2=RxYvH1CG_OR55ZE_3dvulA&bvm=bv.95039771,d.b2w)".

In section 3, page 370, Bjarne said that "The compiler turns a call of a member function into an "ordinary" function call with an "extra" argument; that "extra" argument is a pointer to the object for which the member function is called."

Consider a simple class `A`:

```
class A {
    int a;
    void f(int i);
};
```

A call of the member function A::f:

```
A* pa;
pa->f(2)
```

is transformed by the compiler to an "ordinary function call":

```
f__F1A(pa, 2)
```

pa is passed as the this pointer. It's easy to understand for the above example.

Consider the following code snippet:

```
class A {int a; void f(int);};
class B : A {int b; void g(int);};
class C : B {int c; void h(int);};
```

**Question 1:**

A call of the member function A::f:

```
C* pc = new C;
pc->g(int)
```

is transformed by the compiler to an "ordinary function call":

```
g__G1C(pc, int) or g__G1B((*B)pc, int)
```

Is the this pointer a *pc or (*B)pc?
Another question is how the compile knows where the member functions are?

Let's make the above example more interesting by adding the virtual keyword.

```
class A {
    int a;
    virtual void f(int);
    virtual void g(int);
    virtual void h(int);
};
class B : A {int b; void g(int); };
class C : B {int c; void h(int); };
```

A class c object C looks like:

C:

```
-----------                vtbl:
+0:  vptr -------------->  -----------
+4:  a                     +0: A::f
+8:  b                     +4: B::g
+12: c                     +8: C::h
-----------                -----------
```

A call to a virtual function is transformed into an indirect call by the compiler. For example,

```
C* pc;
pc->g(2)
```

becomes something like:

```
(*((*pc)[1]))(pc, 2)
```

The Bjarne's paper tole me the above conclusion.

**Question 2:**

(1) In the vtbl, I believe these function pointers are assigned during
 the runtime. How does the compiler know the second function pointer
 should point to the class B's implementation of the g? How the
compiler figures it?

(2) In the above example, all members are int and we assume that the
 compiler assigns 4 bytes memory for the int. What if the member is
char, does the compiler still assigns 4 bytes memory for the char? Or just one byte?

(3) `(*((*pc)[1]))(pc, 2)`, the this pointer here is a pc, why not
(*B)pc? Is there any rule for the passing this pointer?

Can anyone help me answer these questions? I really appreciate it. I have a
deadline tomorrow which is really relative to these problems. Please help!!!

Comment: This seems like it's going to take a peek into Clang/GCC to get the answers.

Comment: Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted,

Answer (score 1):

> Question 1:
>
> A call of the member function A::f:
>
> ```
> C* pc = new C;
> pc->g(int)
> ```

This isn't a call to A::f(). It is a call to B::g().

> is transformed by the compiler to an "ordinary function call":

```
g__G1C(pc, int) or g__G1B((*B)pc, int)
```

> Is the this pointer a *pc or (*B)pc?

Neither. It is a `B*`.

> Another question is how the compile knows where the member functions are?

It doesn't. It knows their names. The linker assigns their addresses.

> Question 2:
>
> (1) How does the compiler know the second function pointer should point to the class B's implementation of the g? How the compiler figures it?

Because it is C's vtbl, and C inherits from B, and B has the nearest definition of g().

> (2) In the above example, all members are int and we assume that the compiler assigns 4 bytes memory for the int. What if the member is char, does the compiler still assigns 4 bytes memory for the char? Or just one byte?

It depends on the alignment and packing rules of the processor, the compiler, compiler options, surrounding #pragmas, etc.

> (3) (*((*pc)[1]))(pc, 2), the this pointer here is a pc, why not (*B)pc?

This supposition contradicts [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30747633/207421). It is `B*`.

> Is there any rule for the passing this pointer?

See above.

Comment: thanks so much for your answer. I have another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30747633/compilers-detail-of-this-pointer Can you please help me take a look at it?

Comment: For question 2, the function pointers are pointed to appropriate functions at runtime or at the compile step?

Comment: @Fihop That's not a meaningful question.